# AJAX - Getting info about how to make request from cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cookies

I am new to this and I am not even sure this is possible. I just need to automatically send form with some values (HTML inputs) as AJAX requests, but I don't know where to send it (like URL or something). I've already asked once, and somebody told me that I'm probably trying to hack something, NO! Just want to submit a form with values like you do with keyboard and mouse. I want to use jQuery and Tampermonkey.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the ajax...

The problem is that I don't really understand what do you really want, but when you load your page with this, it will fire a POST-type form submit (but you have to specify that in your data array)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/your/url.php",
            data: yourDataArray, //Create an array variable with your input values
            dataType: "json" //For example, if you want to return json from PHP
            success: function(data){
                console.log("Send");
            }
        });
    });
```